# LWJGL/OpenGL implementation causes NullPointerException error

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

```
package com.flappygame.flappy;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWvidmode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext;

public class Main implements Runnable {

    private int width = 1280;
    private int height = 720;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    private long window;


    public void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Game");
        thread.start();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
            System.err.println("Could not initialize GLFW!");
            return;
        }

        //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
        //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
        //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Flappy", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) {
            System.err.println("Could not create GLFW window!");
            return;
        }

        ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());     
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode) - width) / 2, (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode) - height) / 2);

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwShowWindow(window);     
        //System.out.println("OpenGL version: " + glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    }

    public void run() {
        init();
        while (running) {
            update();
            render();

            if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_TRUE) {
                running = false;
            }

        }
    }

    private void update() {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    private void render() {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
    }

}
```

(this is my whole code)

First of all, I'm using code from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=527bR2JHSR0 (GitHub repo: https://github.com/TheCherno/Flappy). I write this code step by step but I stuck on... Running it (what it ridiculous, I've made only main file). What is important, IMO, I'm using *Eclipse on Mac OS X 10.10.3*. OFC I've added all LWJGL libraries. This is the console error I've got every (fu...) time I'm running the code:

```
Could not create GLFW window!
Exception in thread "Game" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.lwjgl.system.Checks.checkPointer(Checks.java:66)
at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(GLFW.java:2578)
at com.radnok.flappy.Main.render(Main.java:74)
at com.radnok.flappy.Main.run(Main.java:60)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is wrong here? 
I had problem with OpenGL version (commented lines). Maybe that's because of it?

Answer (score 0):

The "Could not create GLFW window!" message makes very clear what is going on. You did not get a GLFW window, but you don't abort the program in this case, and go further on with your `render()` function, feeding `NULL` to `glfWindowShouldClose()`.

You really should remove the `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);` if you are not going to request some >= 3.2 core profile context. But trying to request a GL 4.4 context is also not going to work on OSX. Use something which is actually supported by your OS.

Comment: When I remove `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);` I can see only a wall of red errors in console

Something like:
`*** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-1153.20/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:340`

 `java[3925:2167638] +[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.`

Comment: Well, this is a totally new question, and completely unrelated to OpenGL.

Comment: I think it is related to OpenGL but unrelated to Java. Maybe it's something about Eclipse configuration? I'm using newest JDK and LWJGL version. On Apple's website I can find my Macbook on the list supporting OpenGL 4.1. In fact, on compatibility profile I have version 2.1, on Core profile 4.1. How can I switch it, or... I don't. That's why I need help. I'm new in using Java/Eclipse. I didn't expect troubles on enviroment level.

Comment: It is not related to GL at all. THe error message you get is one of OSX's APIs. The simple solution seems to be to _do the event handling in the main thread_, as the error message actually suggests (I also do not see any reason why you create a separate thread at all). However, I'm not an expert on OSX, and you really should open a new question for this.